# How to add extension settings schema on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The settings in VS Code supports graphic panel like below:

[image]

I am developing an extension in vscode but I couldn't find a document or example to show how to add these settings. Is there any tutorial I can read for doing that?

I tried below configuration but the GUI doesn't show panel for these fields:

```
"configuration": [
      {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "MongoDB Runner Configuration",
        "properties": {
          "mongoRunner": {
            "type": "object",
            "default": {},
            "description": "Complete connection configuration for your MongoDB.",
            "properties": {
              "connection": {
                "title": "MongoDB Runner Configuration",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "url": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "mongodb://",
                    "description": "MongoDB URI"
                  },
                  "activeOnStartUp": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false,
                    "description": "whether launch mongodb runner on start up"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

below is the json file format I need to support:

```
"mongoRunner": {
        "connection": {
            "activeOnStartUp": true,
            "url": "mongodb://localhost:27017"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

Is [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesconfiguration) what you're looking for?
You can use markdown in the description (property *markdownDescription*), and the checkbox appears by using type *boolean*.

**Example:**

```
"configuration": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Test configuration",
        "properties": {
                "test.usingUI": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "markdownDescription": "**Some bold text**\nYes or no?"
                },
                "test.text": {
                        "type": ["string", "null"],
                        "default": null,
                        "description": "You can't edit me now!"
                }
        }
    },
```

Looking in the UI like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqMsE.png)

---

**Edit - 2:**

In this case your syntax is malformed, try this:

```
    "configuration": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "MongoDB Runner Configuration",
        "properties": {
            "mongoRunner.url": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "mongodb://",
                "description": "MongoDB URI"
            },
            "mongoRunner.activeOnStartUp": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "default": false,
                "description": "whether launch mongodb runner on start up"
            }
        }
    },
```

[-> UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQzu.png)

Comment: The contributes configuration works for json schema but it doesn’t come up with the UI. I see some of the extension configurations can be set through the GUI. How can I add my configuration on the GUI panel?

Comment: @ZhaoYi the contributes configuration comes up with the UI, I added an example to my answer

Comment: I added an example as well but it doesn't show the GUI for configuration. Does the configuration have any limitation for the json object?

Comment: I just tried your solution. It doesn't support the nested json object. I have put my schema in the question post.